# Error of text2ltree

Tags: postgresql

Error of text2ltree
I can't use text2ltree. Any suggestion?

SELECT text2ltree(to_char(243, '09999999'))

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at position 0
SQL state: 42601

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it is caused by leading whitespace being returned by to_char.  To fix, use ltrim:

```
SELECT text2ltree(ltrim(to_char(243, '09999999')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT FROM text2ltree(to_char(243, '09999999'))
```